# How do I get a % sign in symbolic x coords in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I have some data I want to plot in a bar chart where the name on the x-axis should have a % sign in it.  So this works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    symbolic x coords={10 perc,20 perc},
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {(10 perc,10) (20 perc,20)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But if I try something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    symbolic x coords={10\%,20\%},
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {(10\%,10) (20\%,20)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Missing \endcsname inserted.

--- TeX said ---
<to be read again> 
                   \%
l.8         ]
```

This happens in and out of math mode.

\\\% causes pdflatex to hang.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LaTeX has a safe percent macro but it uses an `@` name so first give it a name without an `@`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\makeatletter
\let\percent\@percentchar
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    symbolic x coords={10\percent,20\percent},
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {(10\percent,10) (20\percent,20)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this *almost* works!

It gives something like this though:

![Plot](http://i.imgur.com/bIueR.png)

Not sure why the extra x ticks

Comment: Isn't that exactly the same as your first example but with "perc" replaced by `%` ??

Comment: hah, right you are, sorry, was miss-reading.  this works fine thanks.  the only last little niggle is getting there to be a space after the % sign, like if one of the coords was: (Foo 20% Bar,20).  thanks again!

Comment: can't answer your spacing issue (I've never used tikz except for running MWE from questions on this site) If necessary ask another question on site specifically about the spacing

Comment: @nick I guess you get a space the same way you always get one after a macro: `\percent\ bla` (i.e. a ``\`` and a space after the macro) or `\percent{} bla`.

Comment: @Caramdir hah yeah, of course, i should of thought of that.  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ybar,symbolic x coords={10,20},xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$\,\%]
     \addplot coordinates {(10,10) (20,20)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The default for `xticklabel` is defined by (p. 225 in the `pfgplots` manual)

```
\def\axisdefaultticklabel{$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$}
```

Comment: Ahh, I should have been more clear in my question, but I was trying to keep it simple.  Only SOME of my entries have % signs in them.  It's actually entries like: {Housing 10%, Housing 20%, No Housing, Something Else}, so the xticklabel trick doesn't (i think) work.